# How to create a global robots.txt that gets appended to each domain's own robots.txt on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, robots.txt, web-crawler

I know can [create ONE robots.txt file for all domains on an Apache server*](https://serverfault.com/questions/213422/how-to-create-robots-txt-file-for-all-domains-on-apache-server), but I want to **append** to each domain's (if pre-existing) robots.txt. I want some general rules in place for all domains, but I need to allow different domains to have their unique rules.

**Is there a way to accomplish this?**

(*In my case Apache 2.2.x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Apache's point of view, `robots.txt` is just an asset to be served.  You can alter the content returned when `robots.txt` is requested by passing it through an output filter.

If you want to append some text, you could define an [external filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html).  Assuming that Apache is running on Unix-like operating system, the filter configuration could be

```
ExtFilterDefine appendRobotstxt cmd="/bin/cat - /var/www/html/robots-tail.txt"
<Location /robots.txt>
    SetOutputFilter appendRobotstxt
</Location>
```

That would concatenate `robots-tail.txt` to the end of the response.

Comment: Apache is on CentOS 6.3. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how should I define intype so that it only filters robots.txt ?

Comment: @Gaia The filter is activated not by the intype of the filter definition, but by a SetOutputFilter directive.  <Location /robots.txt> SetOutputFilter appendRobotsTail </Location>

Comment: `ExtFilterDefine appendRobotstxt cmd="cat - /root/robots-tail.txt"

<Location /robots.txt>
 SetOutputFilter appendRobotstxt
</Location>`

inside httpd.conf gets me a 500 for robots.txt. I gave /root/robots-tail.txt 777 for testing purposes, and apache runs suexec/fcgid.

Comment: SELinux is disabled. placing the file in public_html in one of the vhosts allows for an error to be displayed: `No such file or directory: couldn't create child process to run cat` followed by `No such file or directory: can't initialise output filter appendrobotstxt: aborting`. Server is running suExec.

Comment: the command needs to begin with `/bin/cat `...  thanks!

Comment: @Gaia I've incorporated your comments into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you'd probably have to incorporate the changes. If a domain already has

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search
```

and you want to add for all domains

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
```

you'd have to make it

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search
Disallow: /admin/
```

because robots.txt parsers stop as soon as they found a block that matches them.

Comment: I want to disallow completely a few user-agents. Thanks.