# How to disallow crawling for all subdomains using my main domain's physical robots.txt file

Tags: apache-2.2, web-crawler, robots.txt

I have multiple physical sub-domains and I don't want to change any robots.txt file of any of that sub-domains.

Is there any way to disallow all the sub-domains from my main domain's physical robots.txt file without using any sub-domain's physical file?

Any common server (Apache's) file which can access all the sub-domains and main domain, too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create robots.txt file for all domains on Apache server](https://serverfault.com/questions/213422/how-to-create-robots-txt-file-for-all-domains-on-apache-server)

Comment: I have physical sub-domains with diff  host server.

Comment: If the subdomains are not on the same server, then there is no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to say anything about `subdomain.example.com` on `example.com/robots.txt`.

The [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) has really limited syntax, e.g.

```
User-agent: Google
Disallow: /administrator

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Where the `User-agent:` defines the search engine and `Disallow:` the path related to server root. In this example `Google` allowed crawl anything but `/administrator`, all disallowed for rest. As always with `robots.txt` it doesn't limit anything; it's merely a beautiful wish not to go there.

The syntax simply has no place for a subdomain and the Web Robot only looks for `/robots.txt` i.e. `subdomain.example.com/robots.txt`, not `example.com/robots.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by 'domain', you mean something like `example.com` and by sub-domain you mean `blerf.example.com`, then I believe the answer to be 'you can't do that'.

The problem is that when a crawler tries to crawl `blerf.example.com`, it looks at `blerf.example.com/robots.txt` to see what it shouldn't crawl. It doesn't look at `example.com/robots.txt`, because that's a different domain.

One explanation of robots.txt operation can be found at http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html .